# JAXB unmarshall: where does ElementNSImpl come from?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

When I unmarshall a certain object I don't get back the type of the object but the type `ElementNSImpl` that appears to have my data in it but why won't JAXB unmarshall it into my JAXB classes?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Asset", propOrder = {
    "platformContentOrFeatureContentOrAirspace",
    ...
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ...
})
public abstract class Asset {
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "PlatformContent", type = AnyPlatform.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "FeatureContent", type = AnyFeature.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "Airspace", type = Airspace.class)
    })
    protected Object platformContentOrFeatureContentOrAirspace;

    ...

    public Object getPlatformContentorFeatureContentorAirspace(){
        return platformContentOrFeatureContentOrAirspace;
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is a schema fragment:

```
<complexType name="Asset">
    <complexContent>
      <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
        <sequence>
          <choice minOccurs="0">
            <element name="PlatformContent" type="temp:TargetNamespaceURI}AnyPlatform"/>
            <element name="FeatureContent" type="{temp:TargetNamespaceURI}AnyFeature"/>
            <element ref="{temp:TargetNamespaceURI}Airspace"/>
          </choice>
        </sequence>
      </restriction>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
```

**UPDATE:**
In this case I am trying to unmarshall XML that contains a PlatformContent tag. If I take out the `@XmlTransient` annotation I get an exception saying that it can't instantiate AnyPlatform. I am very new to JAXB but I realize this may be a false step and side stepping my problem to leave the `@XmlTransient` in.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AnyPlatform", propOrder = {
    "fooOrBarOrBaz"
})
@XmlTransient   //This may be needed to parse correctly.
@XmlSeeAlso({
     AnyPlatformDerivedType1.class,
     AnyPlatformDerivedType2.class
})
public abstract class AnyPlatform {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "Foo", type = Foo.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "Bar", type = Bar.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "Baz", type = Baz.class),
    })
    protected PlatformType fooOrBarOrBaz;

    public PlatformType getFooOrBarOrBaz() {
        return fooOrBarOrBaz;
    }
}
```

Here is the schema fragment

```
<xs:complexType name="AnyPlatform" abstract="true">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="Foo"/>
        <xs:element ref="Bar"/>
        <xs:element ref="Baz"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

When @XmlTransient is taken out I get this exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of AnyPlatform
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.InstantiationException]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:690)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:171)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.XsiTypeLoader.startElement(XsiTypeLoader.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:559)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:125)
    at App.parse(App.java:66)
    at MainWindow$1.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:57)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.createInstance(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:270)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:684)
    ... 60 more
```

UPDATE 2
 Here is the XML in question:

```
<p:AssetList>
  <p:Asset>
    <p:PlatformContent>
      <p:Foo>
        <!-- Foo's Data -->
      </p:Foo>
    </p:PlatformContent>
  </p:Asset>
</p:AssetList>
```

UPDATE3 
  To add more clarity AnyPlatform is the base class for two derived classes. We will call them AnyPlatformDerivedClass1 and AnyPlatformDerivedClass2. Here is what they look like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AnyPlatformDerivedType1")
public class AnyPlatformDerivedType1
    extends AnyPlatform
{
// Yes. These really are empty according to the schema.

}
```

They are blank on purpose according to the schema. So this basically is just the same content with a different XML tag name.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AnyPlatformDerivedType2")
public class AnyPlatformDerivedType2
    extends AnyPlatform
{
// Yes. These really are empty according to the schema.

}
```

Comment: Can you post the XML you are trying to unmarshal?

Comment: See my update. Added XML.

Comment: Sorry, guess I should've seen this without the XML.  PlatformContent maps to AnyPlatform which is abstract.  If you don't have XML transient you get an exception because it can't instantiate an abstract class.  If you do have XML transient you get an ElementNSImpl because that is the default return for elements which don't have a corresponding Java type.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I added some more code. I guess my fundamental question is can you have an abstract class in the type field in the @XmlElement annotation? If not then how would I support XML with tags for AnyPlatformDerived1 and AnyPlatformDerived2?

Comment: If the two types are truly empty and the XML is as you posted how could you even write a parser to know which case you've encountered?  There is no discriminator.  If there is an xsi:type attribute then it can work but I don't recall the exact setup.  I think it would involve removing the transient annotation from AnyPlatform and putting the two derived types in your XmlElements block or using XmlSeeAlso on your AnyPlatform class or possibly by just including your subtypes in your JAXBContext.  I'll do some experiments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the abstract keyword from AnyPlatform. Everything worked as expected, and right now its unlikely for me that it will be needed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It will work sufficiently provided you use xsi:type as the discriminator and the concrete implementations are in the JAXBContext (either added directly or referenced via an XmlSeeAlso).  Here is an example:

```
class QuickTest {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Container {
        @XmlElement
        public Base base;
    }

    public static abstract class Base {

    }

    @XmlType(name="one")
    public static class ChildOne extends Base {

    }

    @XmlType(name="two")
    public static class ChildTwo extends Base {

    }

    private static final String MESSAGE = "<container xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><base xsi:type=\"one\"/></container>";


    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class, Base.class, ChildOne.class, ChildTwo.class);
        Container con = (Container) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(MESSAGE));
        System.out.println(con.base.getClass());
        //Prints QuickTest$ChildOne
    }
}
```

Comment: I had @XmlSeeAlso in my code as shown above, and I have now added to the code above, but you brought up something curious. As of now I have been passing the package name to JAXBContext.newInstance(). Should I be using all of the classes? I have 500+ classes. Also it is another third party application that produces the XML that I am trying to unmarshall so I cant add xsi:type.

Comment: I see the @XmlSeeAlso and that is valid but without the xsi:type what can be done?  If it is AnyPlatformDerivedType1 the XML will be <p:PlatformContent>...</p:PlatformContent> and if it is AnyPlatformDerivedType2 the XML will be <p:PlatformContent>...</p:PlatformContent>.  How is the parser supposed to make the decision?  If this is truly the case then get rid of the concrete types and make the base type non-abstract.

Comment: Don't sweat adding packages.  I only add individual classes for simple examples.  I think the package scanning will only pick up XmlRootElement and descendents so you just have to make sure the concrete classes are in the path of an XmlRootElement (the XmlSeeAlso you have achieves this).  It's possible the package scanning also picks up XmlType entities, I don't know.